# how to configure logrotation for 31st of month or 28/29th day of feb

Tags: logrotate

how can I configure for 31 days of month . currently I am able to do with 30 days.

```
/var/log/myLogs/* {
    daily
    missingok
    rotate 30
    olddir /prar/oney_logs/tomcat_m_logs/archive
    compress
    copytruncate
    postrotate
            ls /prar/oney_logs/tomcat_m_logs/GC_web_*.log |grep -v `date --date 'today' +%y%m%d`| xargs rm -f
                                                            find /prar/oney_logs/tomcat_m_logs/archive/GC_web_*.log* -mtime +30 -exec rm {} \;
    endscript
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not so easy with logrotate. You can set `rotate 31` to keep the max number of days a month can have. Then add a `monthly` cron job to archive the files per month. By setting 31 as the number of logs to keep, you are sure you have at least a months of files. If the month has less the 31 days, you will have 1 or more daily logs from last month left over.

Otherwise you can:
a) Handle by postrotate script in order to rename / move files for maonths with less than 31 days;
b) Make a crontab script to change logrotate config file each month;
c) Make a config file for each month and set 12 entries in crontab as described here: [Logrotate - daily log files for a month](https://www.redhat.com/archives/rhl-list/2007-August/msg03773.html);
d) use some different utilities / program than logrotate